# is it possible to write these 2 lines as Ternary Operators?

Tags: java, if-statement, ternary-operator

Example :

```
if (i < n) 
    i++;
else 
   j += 2;
```

i did :

```
i += i < n ? 1 : j += 2;
```

(but compiler show error)

how can i write those lines as Ternary Operators if it is possible ..
thanks ...

Comment: in one block, you are incrementing i, while in other j. How would you justify `i += i < n ? 1 : j += 2; ` where i>=n? From the looks of it you are trying to increment i..

Comment: I hope this is just an exercise or a curiosity, and you’re not really planning to code like this.  The first version is orders of magnitude more readable.

Comment: @SMA you are right :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(It's the "conditional" operator. It's **a** ternary operator, and for now Java's only one, but...)

Since you're not always changing the value of `i`, and Java doesn't allow arbitrary expressions as standalone statements (like some other languages, such as JavaScript, do), you can't rewrite those using the conditional operator unless you give yourself a `nop` method or something so you can use the conditional in an expression context. Or doing something really convoluted.

There's also no reason to. `if` is quite clear.

But if you wanted to, given:

```
private static void nop(int n) {
}
```

then

```
nop(i < n ? (i = i + 1) : (j = j + 2));
```

There's also this massively-convoluted way:

```
i = i < n ? i + 1 : (j = j + 2) == j ? i : 0;
```

...which just assigns `i` back to itself if `i < n` is false, since we know that `(j = j + 2) == j` will be `true`.

But again: There's no reason to.

Comment: No need to change `i++` to `(i = i + 1)`, and `j += 2` to `(j = j + 2)`. You can still use the `++` and `+=` inside the conditional operator: `int dummy = i < n ? i++ : (j += 2);`

Comment: @Andreas: Did you test that? When I did it, it didn't like `j += 2`. It complained that it found a variable where it expected a value. (Naturally the `i++` is fine.)

Comment: Sorry, fixed that with `()`. Wrong operator precedence without `()`. Same reason you had to use `()`.

Comment: @Andreas: Doh! I should have thought of using parens.

Answer (score 2):

The conditional operator `?` (or ternary operator) is designed to assign a value to a single variable.

[Oracle training/examples](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) documents this operation in this way :

> this operator is also known as the ternary operator because it uses
>   three operands. In the following example, this operator should be read
>   as: "If someCondition is true, assign the value of value1 to result.
>   Otherwise, assign the value of value2 to result."

```
int value1 = 1;
int value2 = 2;
int result;
boolean someCondition = true;
result = someCondition ? value1 : value2;
```

So, no you cannot `directly` use a ternary operator to assign the result to `j` **or** `i`.

---

As T.J. Crowder shown, you could use a convoluted way to use the ternary operator but it would be not readable and error prone.

So the `if` statement should be favored.
Why try to make harder to read a thing actually simple to read ?

Answer (score 2):

Your first code does not return anything, so it is a bad idea to use conditional operator. Just use an `if` statement, it is simpler.